# How to explain the dual constraints for the non-convex QP example?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

This example is drawn from the following slide: http://www.ece.ust.hk/~palomar/ELEC5470_lectures/07/slides_Lagrange_duality.pdf

[image]

The pound symbol denotes the pseudo-inverse. Can someone explain why we need the positive semidefinite constraint on $A+\lambda I $ and more mysteriously, why do we need the range constraint?

I have the feeling that the positive semidefinite is needed to ensure existence of pseudo-inverse (Although I thought every matrix had a pseudo inverse)?

Comment: Every matrix has a pseudoinverse- the positive definiteness constraint is not needed to ensure that a pseudoinverse exists.  If you write out the Lagrangian, you'll be able to see that the inf of the Lagrangian with respect to $x$ is negative infinity exist if $A+\lambda I$ is not positive semidefinite.  Similarly, $b$ must like in the range of $A+\lambda I$ or else the inf is minus infinity.  You should start by writing out the Lagrangian.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Hi, the Lagrangian is $L(x, \lambda) = x^T(A+\lambda I)x + 2b^Tx - \lambda$, and $\nabla L(x,\lambda) = 0 \implies x = -(A + \lambda I)^{\dagger}b$. Suppose that $b$ is not in the range of $A+\lambda I$, then there does not exist some vector $y$ such that $(A + \lambda I) y = b$. This doesn't immediately imply that $x$ must be minus infinity....

Comment: We're interested in the inf of $L(x,\lambda)$, not the value of $x$ at which the inf might be attained.  If $A+\lambda I$ is not positive definite, then $L(x,\lambda)$ is a nonconvex quadratic function of $x$ for fixed $\lambda$, and doesn't have a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrangian is
$$L(x,\lambda) = x^TAx+2b^Tx - \lambda(1-x^Tx) = x^T(A+\lambda I)x + 2b^Tx - \lambda$$
The dual problem is
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & g(\lambda) \\
\text{subject to} & \lambda \geq 0
\end{array}
where $g(\lambda)$, the dual function, is given by
$$g(\lambda) = \inf_x L(x,\lambda) = \inf_x x^T(A+\lambda I)x + 2b^Tx - \lambda$$

*PEDANTRY ALERT:* Note the absence of any other constraints on $\lambda$. How is this possible? Well, the additional constraints are implicit, included in the domain of the dual function, $g$. That is for some values of $\lambda$, the infimum on $x$ is unbounded below; i.e., $g(\lambda) = -\infty$. What we always do is determine just what those domain constraints are, and make them *explicit*, by adding them to the list of dual constraints. Since it's so common to do this we tend to call the resulting model "the dual problem" instead. It is technically *not* the dual, but it is definitely *equivalent* to it.

With that said, let's explain what these implicit constraints are, by expanding just a bit on what Brian said above.

First, suppose $A+\lambda I \not\succeq 0$. Then there is at least one vector $v$ such that $v^T(A+\lambda I)v < 0$. In that case, define $x=t v$, and let $t\rightarrow +\infty$; then $g(tv) \rightarrow -\infty$. Therefore, for $g(\lambda)$ to be finite, it must be the case that
$$A+\lambda I \succeq 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \lambda \geq -\lambda_\min(A)$$
Either one of these will do---$\lambda_\min(\cdot)$ is actually a concave function of its input, so that is a convex constraint in $A$.

Second: consider the optimality condition on $x$:
$$2(A+\lambda I)x + 2 b = 0$$
If $b\not\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A+\lambda I)$, there is no solution to this condition. If this is so, then there must exist a $v$ such that
$$(A+\lambda I)v = 0 \quad b^T v = 1$$
Then letting $x = -tv$ and allowing $t\rightarrow +\infty$ will again drive the infimum to $-\infty.$ So the second implicit constraint is indeed
$$b\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A+\lambda I)$$

If both of these constraints holds, then we have $x=-(A+\lambda I)^\# b$, as the slide says. Substituting this into $g(\lambda)$ yields
$$g(\lambda) = b^T(A+\lambda I)^\#(A+\lambda I)(A+\lambda I)^\# b - 2 b^T (A+\lambda I)^\# b - \lambda$$
which, since $ZZ^\#Z = Z$ for any matrix $Z$, simplifies to
$$g(\lambda) = -b^T(A+\lambda I)^\# b - \lambda$$